# android native lib not installed with APK

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk

I've made an android library project that uses some native libraries.

I've made the jni wrapper and put the native libs (.so) in the libs// folders. The native libs are compiled using cmake, for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 and mips.

I export this project to a jar and put this jar into a "normal" android project. I then export this project to an apk and can see that my libs are bundles into it.

However, when i install the apk, the libs corresponding to the device are not copied into /data/data/com.my.app/lib and obviously, running the app complains about not finding the libs (UnsatisfiedLinkError).

I've search through SO and everywhere i can but found no answer that solved my case.

i'm using Eclipse, btw

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

OK, i've read the doc in the ndk and seen the examples, and unfortunately, i can't see the solution.

The ndk build the c code into shared libs and places them into the appropriated location in the project. But it doesn't generate anything that says that the libs must be installed with the apk.

My goal is to provide an android library (so a jar), that can be included within an android application. I don't see the real difference between what i'm doing (compile the c libs using cmake and package the jni and java compiled classes into a jar) and what is done with android.mk

If you see what i'm missing, feel free to tell me (even if its obvious).

thanks

**UPDATE**

i've made a dirty hack: in the libs folder of my application, i've put the jar file containing my classes and my native libs and a copy of the .so files for each arch. Suprise, the libs are no installed in /data/data/com.me.myapp/lib

It seems to confirm that it's a packaging problem.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation that comes with the NDK.

Comment: You can't just place the library in the NDK project, you have to include it in the Android.mk file - there is plenty of documentation on this as well as examples here on SO

Comment: i've read some doc (not the one of the sdk) on how to build a native lib. But apparently, i've read the wrong docs. I'll have a look and come back later. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried linking your .so file directly instead of putting them into jar? What's the purpose of putting them into jar by the way?

Comment: Thats the point of my second update: if i add the .so directly into the libs folder of my android app, they are installed with the apk. The point of having .so into the jar is to deliver only 1 thing to the other developpers

Answer (score 1):

> I export this project to a jar and put this jar into a "normal"
>   android project. I then export this project to an apk and can see that
>   my libs are bundles into it.

The issue is that the Android packaging system doesn't handle with binary assets in JARs. For your application project to find and include the generated `.so` files, you need it to reference the library project as an 'Android library project':
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you call ndk-build command?

See description below for details.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

> You can build the shared libraries for the sample apps by going into /samples// then **calling the ndk-build command**. The generated shared libraries will be located under /samples//libs/armeabi/ for (ARMv5TE machine code) and/or /samples//libs/armeabi-v7a/ for (ARMv7 machine code).

Comment: my native libs are well build. I do not call myself ndk-build, but it is called by the cmake build. thanks